# Excel vba: .find function returns runtime error 91

Tags: vba, excel, find, runtime-error, max

I've been reading relevant threads for hours now but can't seem to find a solution. Your help would be much appreciated, thank you.

I am trying to find the max value in a range then find which row it was in.
This code works fine for my first 600+ lines of numbers then crashes and gives me Runtime Error 91. It always seems to crash at the same spot independently of what I do.

```
Dim rSearchRange As Range
Dim dMaxToFind As Double
Dim rSolutionrange As Range

Set rSearchRange = Sheets("MySheet").Range(Cells(672, 1), Cells(681, 1))

With Application.WorksheetFunction
       dMaxToFind = .Max(rSearchRange)
End With

'This bit here returns "nothing" even though i found the max value in this range
Set rSolutionrange = rSearchRange _
            .Find(What:=dMaxToFind, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

Looking at my data, it looks like it changes format in those lines?

```
    Row 670 - 0.000458587
    Row 671 - 0.000458587
    Row 672 - 9.80465E-05
    Row 673 - 9.80465E-05
```

Edit:

dMaxToFind returns 9.80465352566588E-05

Cell formula returns 0.0000980465352566588

it is the same value in cells between Range(Cells(672, 1), Cells(681, 1)

it seems like vba fails to understand those two are the same?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: try `... LookIn:=xlValues...`

Comment: `.Find` will return `Nothing` if there's no match for the search criteria. Error 91 is *raised* (not "returned") when you *later* use that `rSolutionRange` object variable and assume it's set to a valid reference (`Nothing` isn't a valid object reference) - you need to check `If rSolutionRange Is Nothing` before you use it.

Comment: Also `Sheets("MySheet").Range(Cells(672, 1), Cells(681, 1))` will blow up if `Sheets("MySheet")` isn't the active sheet, because `Cells(xxx, yyy)` calls are implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, so you need to qualify these calls too; use `With Worksheets("MySheet")` then do `Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(672, 1), .Cells(681,1))` inside the `With` block (notice the dots).

Comment: Thanks guys, still no luck.

Comment: user3598756 - doesn't seem to change the result
Mat's Mug - I tried various ways of calling the row of the range or using the row directly without using the range at all. The range returns nothing and the row therefore returns error 91.
I incorporated with worksheets("MySheet") as well with no luck

Comment: `Find` returns `Nothing` when the search fails to find a result, that's just how it works - if your code raises error 91, you're failing to verify the object has a reference before you use it. Fix that, *then* figure out why the search is failing.

Comment: What is the value of `dMaxToFind` when `Find` fails to return an object reference? Step through the code (F8), use breakpoints (F9), watch locals. Please [edit] your post to include enough information to reproduce the problem. [I cannot reproduce this issue with the provided information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M7RB.png)

Comment: Thanks Mat's Mug - original edited, I hope this helps

Comment: Is `dMaxToFind` declared anywhere? With an explicit type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function which will directly tell you the line number. This is opposed to your method of using in built functions to get the max value and then find it again!

```
Function GetMaxRow(ByRef myRange As Range) As Long

    Dim aCell As Range

    Dim maxVal As Double
    Dim maxRow As Long

    maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRange)
    maxRow = 0

    For Each aCell In myRange

        If aCell.Value > maxVal Then

            maxRow = aCell.row
            maxVal = aCell.Value

        End If

    Next aCell

    GetMaxRow = maxRow

End Function
```

You may want to add some error checking code to the result of this function, for instance when the function returns 0 it would mean you didn't pass it a range with more than 1 cell.

Example:

```
1 - 3.0
2 - 5.2
3 - 7.8
4 - 2.2
5 - 4.5
6 - 3.6

Dim rw as Long
rw = GetMaxRow(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6"))
' >> rw = 3
```

Edit:

You queried the use of loops, presumably because of time savings. Below is a table of timings, of course this will vary between computers but you can see it is a fairly quick routine unless your dataset is massive... Also the order of the operation is linear, as expected, meaning doubling the range roughly doubles the time taken.

```
2000  rows: 0.0050000s
4000  rows: 0.0099219s
8000  rows: 0.0196875s
16000 rows: 0.0392969s
```

The cell values tested over were random doubles between 0 and 1.

Edit 2:

You peaked my interest on speed... So instead of looping over a range (slow) I have written the same function but using an array. The range gets converted to an array, then looped over. This offers speed improvements of ~10x! See below for code and timings on same data.

```
Function GetMaxRow(ByRef myRange As Range) As Long

    Dim i As Long

    Dim maxVal As Variant
    Dim maxRow As Long

    maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRange)
    maxRow = 0

    Dim myArray() As Variant
    myArray = myRange

    For i = 1 To myRange.Count

        If myArray(i, 1) > maxVal Then

            maxRow = i
            maxVal = myArray(i, 1)

        End If

    Next i

    GetMaxRow = myRange.Cells(maxRow).Row

End Function
```

Timings:

```
2000  rows: 0.0006250s
4000  rows: 0.0018750s
8000  rows: 0.0034375s
16000 rows: 0.0068750s
```

Comment: This looks good - is there any way of doing the same thing without looping?

Comment: @Mark, I've added a much quicker version, see Edit 2

Comment: @Mark No worries, be aware that there is **no error checking** in the functions above. I haven't tested, for instance, what happens if your range contains strings (probably okay but might give unexpected results) or error codes (like `#DIV/0!` or `#VALUE!`, which might crash the function!)